# How do I read a compound dataset in HDF.PInvoke that contains an array (of a fixed size) using C#

Tags: c#, marshalling, hdf5

I have an HDF5 dataset that I am trying to read using C# and HDF.PInvoke (basically a wrapper around the C API).

It contains a section holding an array of a compound data type. The datatype contains an array which has 9 elements. When I run the code I get an error when I try to create the `GCHandle` saying:-

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data. (Parameter 'value')
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
```

The error seems to be occurring because of a discrepancy between the desired fixed size of the double[9] array and the actuality of passing an array with `GCHandle` (expecting a pointer perhaps?)
The code works for compound types that do not include arrays.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

A simplified version of my code follows:-

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 76, Pack = 1)]
public struct TestData
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public double[] ArrayVariable = new double[9];
  [FieldOffset(72)]
  public Single FloatVariable = 0;                
   
  public TestData(){}
}
    
public static TestData[] LoadTestData(hid_t pg, string item)
{
  hid_t memtype = H5T.create(H5T.class_t.COMPOUND, (ssize_t)76);
  hsize_t[] array_dims = { 9 };
  hid_t compoundTypeID= H5T.array_create(H5T.NATIVE_DOUBLE, 1, array_dims);
   
  H5T.insert(memtype, "ArrayVariable", (ssize_t)0, compoundTypeID);//+72
  H5T.insert(memtype, "FloatVariable", (ssize_t)72, H5T.NATIVE_FLOAT);//+4
    
  TestData[] testData = null;
  if (TryOpenDataSet(pg, item, out hid_t dataset))
  {                
   hid_t dataspace = H5D.get_space(dataset);
   int rank = H5S.get_simple_extent_ndims(dataspace);
   if (rank == 1)
   {
     hsize_t[] dims = new hsize_t[1];
     hsize_t[] maxdims = new hsize_t[1];
     int tst = H5S.get_simple_extent_dims(dataspace, dims, maxdims);
     if (tst != 1)
     {
       throw new HDF5Exception("unexpected dimension number in TestData Array loading");
     }
     int numEntries = (int)dims[0];
     testData = new TestData[numEntries];   
     hid_t datatype = H5D.get_type(dataset);

     GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(testData, GCHandleType.Pinned);//****Error here****

     H5D.read(dataset, memtype, H5S.ALL, H5S.ALL,  H5P.DEFAULT, pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject());
     pinnedArray.Free();
                           
     H5T.close(datatype);
   }
   H5D.close(dataset);
 }
 return testData;
}

public static bool TryOpenDataSet(hid_t loc_id, string title, out hid_t datasetID)
{
  try
  {
    datasetID = H5D.open(loc_id, title);
    return !(datasetID < 0);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    datasetID = -1;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code as mentioned in the question is that an exception is thrown in the `GCHandle.Alloc(...)` method because the testData array contains non-blittable components.
The solution is to create a buffer array of bytes and use that for the `GCHandle`. A simple `BinaryReader` loop can then be used to assign the correct element of the data to the correct datatype:-

So first we replace the code around the `H5D.Read` section above with :-

```
... 
    int numEntries = (int)dimsFam[0];
    hid_t datatype = H5D.get_type(dataset);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[numEntries * 76];// 76 is the size of TestData
    GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    H5D.read(dataset, memtype, H5S.ALL, H5S.ALL, H5P.DEFAULT, pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    pinnedArray.Free();
    testData = ReadObjectsFromBuffer(buffer, numEntries);
    H5T.close(datatype);
...
```

Where, for the specific case of the TestData structure we have:-

```
private static TestData[] ReadObjectsFromBuffer(byte[] buffer, int num)
{
   TestData[] res = new TestData[num];
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))            
     using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms)) 
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
       {
          res[i] = new TestData();
          for (int j = 0; j < res[i].ArrayVariable.Length; j++)            
             res[i].ArrayVariable[j] = br.ReadDouble();            
          res[i].FloatVariable = br.ReadSingle();
       }
     }            
     return res;
}
```

If there is a better solution that doesn't involve looping through the data explicitly, I would be interested to learn about it.